# Unable to load the images in my imageview with Android Picasso

Tags: android, listview, imageview, picasso

Please I need help. I'm unable to load the images in my imageview;

it gives me the following message:
LogCat:

> 2019-11-22 09: 02: 25.668 10976-10976 / com.acme.crazy W / ImageView:
>   resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
>   https://acme.com/storage/1/1234.png

Thanks in advance.

Magoo

```
public void load(){

        url = "https://acme.com/webservices/json.php?idresp="+IdR+"&idinst="+IdI;
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");
                    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
                    data = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject loginApp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        datanum.put("A", loginApp.getString("IdA"));
                        datanum.put("B", loginApp.getString("IdI"));
                        datanum.put("C", "https://acme.com/storage/" + loginApp.getString("IdI") + "/" + loginApp.getString("Mat").trim() + ".png");
                        datanum.put("D", loginApp.getString("No"));
                        datanum.put("E", loginApp.getString("Ma"));
                        datanum.put("F", loginApp.getString("Se"));
                        datanum.put("G", loginApp.getString("Sa"));
                        Picasso.get().load(datanum.put( "H", "https://acme.com/storage/" + loginApp.getString("IdI") + "/" + loginApp.getString("Mat").trim() + ".png");
                        data.add(datanum);
                    }
                    String[] from = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"};
                    int[] views = {R.id.tvA, R.id.tvB, R.id.tvC, R.id.tvD, R.id.tvE, R.id.tvF, R.id.tvG, R.id.ivSelImgH};
                    AD = new SimpleAdapter(SelectActivity.this, data, R.layout.activity_select_modelo, from, views);
                    lva.setAdapter(AD);

                } catch (JSONException jse){
                    popDialog("Test", "Json Error" + jse.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    popDialog("Tst", "This indicates that the reuest has either time out or there is no connection");
                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    popDialog("Tst", "Error indicating that there was an Authentication Failure while performing the request");
                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                    popDialog("Tst", "Indicates that the server responded with a error response :" + error.getMessage());
                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                    popDialog("Tst", "Indicates that there was network error while performing the request");
                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                    popDialog("Tst", "Indicates that the server response could not be parsed");
                }
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: On the server no image found I have try your url but it was give me 404 error, mean that no data found.

Comment: I have not published the actual url of the application thanks so much for the help.
Actually I only have the problem using Picasso when loading the image.
Tks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the image and then set it as bitmap. Here is one of the many examples. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

or you can use Glide which is much better than picasso and easy to use too.

Example:

```
Glide.with(Activity)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.drawable_name)
```